# Display occurrences count in NSSearchField

Tags: cocoa, nssearchfield

I have an NSSearchField in IB connected to my controller that search on a NSTextView using NSTextfield delagate methods, and I can find and store in an array all ranges of particular text placed in the search field.
The question is:
how can I show a number directly in the NSSearchField like Apple Text Edit does?

[image]

What I tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sf : NSSearchField?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   (self.sf?.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).cancelButtonCell?.title = "22"
   (self.sf?.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).cancelButtonCell?.imagePosition = .imageRight
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

Comment: Also a link to /document/sample code/tutorial for the specific purpose it's enough.

Comment: really I can't found nothing about...

Comment: At the time I wrote this question I give up. Added a little field nearthe search field to display the occurences found. Now I realize that the cancelButton inside the NSSearchFieldCell .... is a button :-), and in fact I can set the title.  Only I cannot found a way to resize the cancelButton cell. I set the image position to right: (self.sf?.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).cancelButtonCell?.title = "22"
       (self.sf?.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).cancelButtonCell?.imagePosition = .imageRight, but the text is not visible yet. Any help?